# Facebook sharer, thumb is showed instead of large image

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sharer

I have set up a contest, the contestants are asked to share their results on facebook.

I have the following button to share the results:

`print('<a class="facebook stemspeler" style="color:#eec920; margin-right:15px;" target="_blank" onclick="return !window.open(this.href, \'Facebook\', \'width=1200,height=300\')" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.***.com%2Fallstars&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.***.com%2Ftypo.php?id='.$makeUniq.'&title=tet&caption=test&quote=test&description=test">‌​Share</a>');`

The $makeUniq makes sure that facebook fetches the results instead of caching the results the first time (When link stays the same it caches, now it doesn't because link changes every request).

The typo.php is the file that houses the image. It takes a standard template and transforms the contest inputs to a image overlay.

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate,    max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);

header("Pragma: no-cache");

// Output to browser
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create a 300x150 image

//WHITE BACKGROUND COLOR
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(1000, 1000);

$im = imagecreatefrompng("images/test.png");

$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$test = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 0);

// Set the background to be white
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 900, 990, $test);

// Path to our font file
$font       = 'fonts/DINPro-Medium.ttf';
$fontSize   = 24;
$angle      = 0;

$x = 80;
$y = 150;
// Write it
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $angle, $x, $y, $white, $font, ' : n');

$x = 80;
$y = 200;
// Write it
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $angle, $x, $y, $white, $font, 'k : ');


$x = 80;
$y = 250;
// Write it
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $angle, $x, $y, $white, $font, 'Ler :n');


$x = 80;
$y = 300;
// Write it
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $angle, $x, $y, $white, $font, 'Mouwer : ');

$x = 80;
$y = 350;
// Write it
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $angle, $x, $y, $white, $font, 'Rwer n');

$x = 80;
$y = 400;
// Write it
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $angle, $x, $y, $white, $font, 'Rechtk : ');

$x = 80;
$y = 450;
// Write it
imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $angle, $x, $y, $white, $font, 'Cir : ');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

Up till here everything works like its supposed to be.

The problem is that when the facebook share functionality opens, facebook keeps showing the image as thumbnail instead of large image.

[image: The way it shows now]

And the result I'm aiming for is the large image:
[image: The way I would like it to show]

I have tried to change resolution many times, and there are several posts on the internet that are close to describe this problem.
Anybody has any idea how I could fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The recommended picture size for a shared link on Facebook is 1200x630. If the picture is too small, Facebook will center crop it and only show a thumbnail of the picture. I believe de minimum size is 600x315, but the result might not be as good on high resolution devices. If you want it to look good and show the full size picture on all devices, use 1200x630px pictures.

You can find a references to those best practices 
[here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices).

**EDIT:**

Your problem might be due to the fact that the Facebook crawler caches the info it crawls, so your old picture might still be used by FB even if you fixed its resolution. Make sure to go [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), to force the Facebook crawler to re-crawl you website and get the new data or simply empty its cache for a particular URL to force it to recrawl your website next time you share the link. Otherwise FB probably still use you old picture it already has in its cache.

Comment: I have tried to use these dimentions but I get the same result. Is it possible to send a height and width as anparameter in the url?

Comment: @FrankW. I edited my answer above. - Might be a cache issue.

Comment: The og:image:heigth & go:image:width meta tags mentioned by Alberto are only used by the crawler the very first time it crawls a URL with nothing in cache. If you do not include them, you will not see the image preview in the Facebook share dialog the very first time as it must be loaded async. If you include them, you will be able to see the image preview in the share dialog even if the crawler as nothing in cache yet as it will be able to load it synchronously. After the Facebook crawler as everything cached, those tags are no longer useful, so this is not what is causing your issue.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I don't send the meta's on the page but I include them as parameters in my url. The reason I have to do that is because I dont want facebook to cache the image (every person that participates in the content has a different outcome). Even by using the parameters within the url it cached the content. Managed to work my way around that by using a md5(rand()) so every string is unique.

So to get to the point, Im sure it doesnt cache the image, every time i hit the share button the data that comes on top of the image is unique and as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify these OG elements:

```
og:image:width 
og:image:height
```

these tags helps crawlers to obtain you image size before dowload it. Maybe you're getting a smaller image preview because crawler didn't get the right size at first and now you're getting preview from a cache.

**EDIT:**
Of course you should be sure that you're using an image that is at least 1200 x 630 px